# Add custom checkbox to flow edit screen

Tags: visual-workflow, aura, checkbox, screen-flow

I am editing flow screen and want to add some components, but i want to add checkbox that will show or remove comonent ( its like show header and show footer). Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screen_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5). Which is describes the conditional visibility of flow elements in SFDC.

And you can use this [blog](https://jenwlee.com/2021/06/11/use-component-visibility-to-show-information-at-the-right-time-in-screen-flow/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20component%20visibility%20in%20a%20Screen,visibility%20is%20set%20on%20the%20Display%20Text%20component.) for your reference.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Actually i thought aboout adding checkbox into right screen with editing, but due to blod there are another way to do it.